# Retrieving a Return value from a Deferred.Done

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I have various javascript controllers. The base HTML document Calls a javascript object, which calls another one, that calls a Ajax call and returns the Deferred object. Then I call .done on that data return and process it. When I process it I check if the data contains a error. I want to be able to return a true or false all the way back up the chain to the base HTML document to perform some UI behavior but I'm quite new to the idea of Deferred/promise. As you can see from the code sample at the last level. I just do return   def.done(AfterServerSuccess) and return all the way back to the base to populate containError. This seems to return an empty Deferred object. I feel like there is a simple answer to this. I've tried different ways to get the boolean out of the done method to be passed up but I can't figure it out. Can someone please provide me some guidance here?

**base:**

```
 var containError =    `myJavascriptController.CheckItemsForErrors(dayparts, false);`
```

**MyJavascriptController.js:**

```
  var CheckItemsForErrors = function (list, source)
        {
           return mySelectionController.CheckForErrors("CheckForErrors", list, source);
        };
```

**mySelectionController.js:**

```
    var CheckForErrors= function (listItems, source)
        {


            if (listItems.length > 1)
            {
                           //Ajax call returns Deferred object
                var def = _manager.SendDataToServer(listItems);

                   return def.done(AfterServerSuccess)
}

 var AfterServerSuccess = function (data)
        {
            _.each(data, function (item)
            {
                if (item.Error == true)
                {
                    return true;
                }

            });

            return false;
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend doing some reading about promises and deferred objects. [This](https://www.promisejs.org/) is a good resource for getting started.

Basically, you need to make your `CheckForErrors` function return a deferred object/promise, which will be resolved by the result of the `AfterServerSuccess` function. Then, at the top level, you can write something like this to get the error result:

```
var containError = false;
myJavascriptController.CheckItemsForErrors(listItems, source)
    .done(function (result) {
        containError = result;
        // Do other stuff here...
    });
```

Work backwards from this little snippet of code and you'll get a feel for the way promises/deferred objects work.